# Infinite AJAX Scroll next, and back?

Tags: seo, infinite-scroll, usability, jquery-ias

I am using Jquery plugin Infinite AJAX Scroll with History Extension in order to change the page URL while scrolling.

Now, let’s say, I scroll down to the 6th ajax load, the page URL has now changed to hostname/?page=6. If you then reload this link, you will see only the page 6 items. If you scroll down, the plugin will load the page 7 and so on.
But, if you scroll up, you wont’t see previous items: page 5, 4, 3...

Here you can see a demo from [John Mueller](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts)

http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=5

It would be nice to have the same behaviour on Jquery IAS, but I think there is no option to enable this functionality in Jquery IAS, is there?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like InfiniteAjaxScroll already does that.  Maybe the phrasing of your question needs some clarification.  https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/history.html